# How many elements in $\hom_{\mathbb F_2}(\mathbb F_2^2,\mathbb F_2^2)?$

Tags: linear-transformations, finite-fields

My syllabus says that $\hom_{\mathbb F_2}(\mathbb F_2^2,\mathbb F_2^2)$ contains 16 elements. I’m guessing this is because $\mathbb F_2^{2\times 2}$ contains 16 elements, but I don’t see why this should be the reason.

It happens to be that we also have three bases for $\mathbb F_2^2$, so shouldn’t there be $< 16$ linear maps? Some linear map could be represented by several matrix representations, i.e. some of  the matrices in $\mathbb F_2^{2\times 2}$ are similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $\hom_{\mathbb{F}_2}(\mathbb{F}_2^2, \mathbb{F}_2^2)$ can be identified with $M_{2}(\mathbb{F}_2)$ (matrices of size $2\times 2$ with entries from $\mathbb{F}_2$). The association is not hard as every linear transformation corresponds to a matrix after you fix a basis. 
If you believe this, then it can be seen that $|M_{2}(\mathbb{F}_2)|=2^4=16$.

Comment: How can we identify those two sets, when one linear map might correspond to two different matrices (different bases).

Comment: Indeed, one linear map can correspond to two different matrices (in different bases) BUT after you fix a basis, you can associate a unique matrix with a linear transformation.

Comment: Similarity as a relation between matrices(if you have already fixed a basis) or as a relation on $\hom_{\mathbb{F}_2}(\mathbb{F}_2^2,\mathbb{F}_2^2)$ is not capturing the number of different linear transformations from $\mathbb{F}_2^2$ to itself. It is counting all the matrices/linear transformations with the same determinant and same trace.  Since determinant and trace can only take the values $0$ or $1$ we have at most $4$ equivalence classes of matrices upto similarity. But clearly you can find more than 4 linear transformations from $\mathbb{F}_2^2$  to itself.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment that you're answering, because I figured it out.  I think it must have happened simultaneously? Next time I might add a comment that I got it, instead of deleting the previous one. Anyhow, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider $\mathrm{Hom}_F(V,W)$ where $F$ is a field, and
$V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over $K$ with dimensions $m$ and $n$.
Then $\mathrm{Hom}_F(V,W)$ is a vector space of dimension $mn$; it
corresponds to the $m\times n$ matrices over $K$.

In this example $K=\Bbb F_2$ and $m=n=2$. So we get a vector space
of dimension $4$ over $\Bbb F_2$. It has order $|\Bbb F_2|^4=2^4=16$.

Comment: How did you come up with $\vert \mathbb F_2\vert^2$? Also, shouldn't it then be $\vert \mathbb F_2\vert^4$?

Comment: For the case  $|Hom_{\mathbb F_9^3}(\mathbb F_9^3, \mathbb F_9^5)|$ would that mean $m=3,n=5 $ and thus $|\mathbb F_9|^{15}=9^{15}=205891132094649$? Or do I understand something wrong?